# Autofill multiple input boxes in the same class with another input on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a fairly easy problem. I have found similar posts on this however, i tried them and it's not working for me. I have a checkbox and onclick of that checkbox i want to fill the remaining boxes with same value. I tried it using two different ways. This one just fills out one input box only.

```js
function autoFunction() {
 if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked) {
  var disk = document.getElementById("value").value;
         document.getElementById("used").value = disk;
 }
 else {
   document.getElementById("used").value = "";
 }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="left">Input Value <input type="text" size="5" id="value" >

&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="autoFunction()"/> Use Default Value</div>
<br>
<div>
<div><input type="text" class="used" id = "used" name= "used" value=""></div>
</div>

<div>
<div><input type="text" class="used" id = "used" name= "used" value=""></div>
</div>

<div>
<div><input type="text" class="used" id = "used" name= "used" value=""></div>
</div>

<div>
<div><input type="text" class="used" id = "used" name= "used" value=""></div>
</div>
```

I tried it with jQuery also. However, it won't display anything.

```
jQuery(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function() {

  if(this.checked) {
   alert("checked ");
    //get the values of the filled fields
    var value = jQuery(".value").val();


    jQuery(".used").val(value);


  }
  else{
   jQuery('.used').val('');
  }
 });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your second attempt looks close, however `checkbox` is an id, not a class.  Same with `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced `if (this.checked)` with    `if  (jQuery('.checkbox').is(':checked'))` and it worked.

```
 jQuery(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function() {
        if  (jQuery('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {

        //get the values of the filled fields
        var disksheettcsn = jQuery(".disksheettcsn").val();

        // then add those values to your billing infor window feilds 
        jQuery(".used").val(disksheettcsn);

        // then form will be automatically filled .. 

      }
      else{
       jQuery('.used').val('');
      }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Jquery selector to "#" instead of "." for value and Checkbox control. this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)  explain you the the difference

```
jQuery(document).on("change", "#checkbox", function() {

  if(this.checked) {
   alert("checked ");
    //get the values of the filled fields
    var value = jQuery("#value").val();


    jQuery(".used").val(value);


  }
  else{
   jQuery('.used').val('');
  }
 });
```